# How do I solve the LEAD fucntion error in this code for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

i'm using SQLite and trying to use the Lead function but I keep getting an error message (pasted below) from my DB Browser. Does anyone know what the issue is? And also, could you please talk me through your thought process of how you would debug the error below? Thank you so much in advance

**MY CODE**

```
SELECT Day.Close, Day.Open, Day.Close - Day.Open AS Movement1, LEAD Day.Close OVER (ORDER BY Day.High) AS Movement2 FROM ES_SourceNT_Day_ADX14 AS Day;
```

**RESPONSE FROM DB BROWSER**

```
near ".": syntax error: SELECT Day.Close, Day.Open, Day.Close - Day.Open AS Movement1, LEAD Day.
```

Comment: Wait, your query was fine the way it was. See my answer. But removing those parentheses definitely won't make the syntax error go away.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot the closing quotes at the end of `"N/A`, and you can explicitly specifying the table name (or even specifying a table alias to begin with) is superfluous if you only have one table, so your query can be written as

```
SELECT Close, Open, Close - Open AS Movement1, LEAD (Close, 1, "N/A") OVER (ORDER BY High) AS Movement2 FROM ES_SourceNT_Day_ADX14;
```

But this is not the problem. In fact **you have no problem if you are using SQLite version 3.25.0 or newer**, but unfortunately earlier versions had no support for window functions.
See the [changelist](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html).

As for my thought process, at first I just tried to simplify your query, removing everything that seemed to be correct, to find a minimal bug repro, the shortest possible code that still produces the error. I went as far as to shorten it to

```
SELECT lead(High) OVER (ORDER BY High) FROM ES_SourceNT_Day_ADX14;
```

then

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY High) FROM ES_SourceNT_Day_ADX14;
```

Still didn't work, and I didn't know why, but I was starting to get suspicious.
I looked up the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html), and tried to run the simplest example, but to no avail. That's when I figured it out. SQLite is famously well tested, if such a huge subset of features doesn't work at all, the most likely explanation is that it is **not supposed to work**, at least not in this version.
Reading the changelist confirmed my theory.

Comment: Ok thankyou, I see your thought process now. It never occurred to me to check whether the features were even compatible so my logic stopped short. My next question is how on earth do I upgrade the SQLite database file? I created it with DB Browser, in Windows. There doesn't seem to be any documentation out there on SQLite.org or the DB browser website, nothing in forums either for Windows.

Comment: If you are using SQLite2, you can upgrade to SQLite3 as described here: https://www.sqlite.org/version3.html

If you are already using SQLite3, just an earlier subverison, then no need to convert anything, you can simply manipulate the file using a more recent command line tool. Not that it might not work the other way though, once you edit a file with SQLite 3.25.0 you might or might not be able to open that with e.g. version 3.10.0.